# Rendering a collection in Backbone

Tags: backbone.js

I have a model working which looks something like this

```
collection=
{
foo:[ [1,1], [2,2], [3,3] ] 
bar: [ [1,1], [2,2], [3,3] ] 
}
```

I am rendering this out to view in backbone by doing this:

```
template: JST["backbone/templates/first"]
collection.each (data) ->
      foo = data.attributes.foo
      bar = data.attributes.bar
      for foos in foo
        view = new Traveltime.Views.ViewExtractTimeList(model: foos)
        $('ul.listcontainer').append(view.render().el)
      for bars in bar
        console.log perce
        view = new Traveltime.Views.ViewExtractPercentList(model: bars)
        $('ul.2ndlistcontainer').append(view.render().el)
```

Template first:

```
<ul class="listcontainer">
</ul>

<ul class="2ndlistcontainer">
</ul>
```

I then have 2 more views which handle a seperate tempate each:

```
class App.Views.ViewExtractFoo extends Backbone.View

  tagName: "li"
  template: JST['backbone/templates/foo']

  render: ->
    $(@el).html(@template(content: @model))
    this


class App.Views.ViewExtractBar extends Backbone.View

  tagName: "li"
  template: JST['backbone/templates/bar']

  render: ->
    $(@el).html(@template(content: @model))
    this
```

template looks like this (swap foo for bar for bar example):

```
<li>
Foo: <%=content.attributes.foo%>
</li>
```

Now this works, and it works well. But it feels REALLY messy. I am using backbone in rails so have like 6 or more different files just take a JSON request and rendering it. It feels nasty and there is a better way. I am just not sure which one it is yet.

I am just thinking if I did this in Rails i could have one view that could pull this all out!?

Can i use collection.each and somehow pass the nested collection to the template?

Bit stuck here, and I am by no means good at this so any help is greatly received.

Comment: Is there anything I can add to help? It just seemed a long way round for me

Answer (score 0):

Simplifying and unifying your templates and views is one option. Templates can use json objects, so they can render arrays, which lends itself well for rendering lists like in your case. For example, you could have just one ListView that does the actual rendering for any list using a single template, and then reuse this view in your main view for both properties of your collection object. Hopefully the next example gives you an idea of where and how you can simplify.

```
class ListView extends Backbone.View 
   tagName: 'ul'
   template: """
        {{#items}}
           <li>{{content}}</li>
        {{/items}}
    """
   render: ->
       @$el.html @template items: @options.items
       @

class MainView extends Backbone.View

    render: ->
        @$el.empty()
        for own subitems of @options.items
            @$el.append new ListView items: subitems
        @



# Example usage #
collection = 
    foo: [[1,1], [2,2], [3,3]] 
    bar: [[1,1], [2,2], [3,3]] 

$('body').append new MainView(items: collection).render().$el
```